# Adding extra int variable to asprintf string causes segmentation fault.

Tags: c

I am currently working on a C project and I am having a rather strange problem that I don't understand.

I am building up an SQL statement using asprintf which is working fine until I add an int variable to the string it then causes a segmentation fault. Below is the code I have for the function.

```
int drilldownSetRowData(callLogSearchDataStruct * callLogSearchData, int dataRow, MYSQL *HandleDB, long inboundEpochTimeStamp)
{
    char * inboundSql = NULL;
    char * sql = NULL;
    int sqlLen = 0;
    char * tempSql = NULL;
    char * outboundSql = NULL;

    char epochBuffer[11];
    int outboundLegCounter = 0;
    callLogSearchOutboundStruct * outboundLeg = NULL;
    if (dataRow == -1)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    char durationBuffer[8];

    snprintf(durationBuffer, sizeof(durationBuffer), "%.1f", callLogSearchData[dataRow].duration);
    snprintf(epochBuffer, sizeof(epochBuffer), "%ld", inboundEpochTimeStamp);

    asprintf(&inboundSql, "INSERT INTO DataTable VALUES (%i, %i, '%s', '%s', %i),"
        "(%i, %i, '%s', '%s', %i), (%i, %i, '%s', '%s', %i), (%i, %i, '%s', '%s', %i),"
        "(%i, %i, '%s', '%s', %i), (%i, %i, '%s', '%s', %i)",
        dataRow, D_DATE, callLogSearchData[dataRow].date, epochBuffer, outboundLegCounter,
        dataRow, D_TIME, callLogSearchData[dataRow].time, epochBuffer, outboundLegCounter,
        dataRow, D_APARTY, callLogSearchData[dataRow].aParty, epochBuffer, outboundLegCounter,
        dataRow, D_BPARTY, callLogSearchData[dataRow].bParty, epochBuffer, outboundLegCounter,
        dataRow, D_DURATION, durationBuffer, epochBuffer,outboundLegCounter,
        dataRow, D_RESULT, callLogSearchData[dataRow].cleardownCause, epochBuffer, outboundLegCounter);

    for (outboundLeg = callLogSearchData[dataRow].outboundLegs; outboundLeg != NULL && outboundLeg->target != NULL; outboundLeg = outboundLeg->nextLeg)
    {
        outboundLegCounter++;
        snprintf(durationBuffer, sizeof(durationBuffer), "%.1f", outboundLeg->duration);

        if (outboundSql == NULL)
        {
            printf("outboundSql is NULL\n");
            asprintf(&tempSql, "(%i, %i, '%s', '%s', 6),"
                "(%i, %i, '%s', '%s', 7), (%i, %i, '%s', '%s', 8)",
                dataRow, D_TARGET, outboundLeg->target, epochBuffer,
                dataRow, D_TARGET_DURATION, durationBuffer, epochBuffer,
                dataRow, D_TARGET_RESULT, setCallResultBackToCallResultNumber(outboundLeg->cleardownCause));
        }
        else
        {
            printf("outboundSql is not NULL\n");
            asprintf(&tempSql, "%s, (%i, %i, '%s', '%s', %i),"
                    "(%i, %i, '%s', '%s', %i), (%i, %i, '%s', '%s', %i)",
                outboundSql, dataRow, D_TARGET, outboundLeg->target, epochBuffer, outboundLegCounter,
                dataRow, D_TARGET_DURATION, durationBuffer, epochBuffer, outboundLegCounter,
                dataRow, D_TARGET_RESULT, setCallResultBackToCallResultNumber(callLogSearchData->cleardownCause), epochBuffer, outboundLegCounter);
        }

    }
    outboundSql = tempSql;
    if (outboundSql != NULL)
    {
        sqlLen = asprintf(&sql, "%s, %s", inboundSql, outboundSql);
    }
    else
    {
        sqlLen = asprintf(&sql, "%s", inboundSql);
    }
    SL_DebugAll(DBG_INFO, sql);
    if ((mysql_real_query(HandleDB, sql, sqlLen))) return 1;

    return 0;
}
```

The problem is on the following lines:

```
if (outboundSql == NULL)
        {
            printf("outboundSql is NULL\n");
            asprintf(&tempSql, "(%i, %i, '%s', '%s', %i),"
                "(%i, %i, '%s', '%s', %i), (%i, %i, '%s', '%s', %i)",
                dataRow, D_TARGET, outboundLeg->target, epochBuffer, outboundLegCounter
                dataRow, D_TARGET_DURATION, durationBuffer, epochBuffer, outboundLegCounter,
                dataRow, D_TARGET_RESULT, setCallResultBackToCallResultNumber(outboundLeg->cleardownCause), outboundLegCounter);
        }
```

If I remove the outboundLegCounter parameter from the asprintf and hard code an int value into the string (replacing the %i on the end of each row insert) the program works fine but using the parameter it throws a segmentation fault.

As you can see in the code the outboundLegCounter is set to 0 and the first thing that happens in the loop is outboundLegCounter is incremented so I don't understand why this is causing a seg fault.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing an `epochBuffer` on this line:

```
dataRow, D_TARGET_RESULT, setCallResultBackToCallResultNumber(outboundLeg->cleardownCause), outboundLegCounter);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I don't know how many times I've looked at the code and not noticed it.

Answer (score 1):

It look like you are missing one parameter. The format string contain 15 arguement and you give it 14. So the `outboundLegCounter` is treat as `%s`.

Dereferencing an integer certainly generate a segfault.